# Show that if G is a simple, regular graph, then every vertex has the same amound of vertices on distance 2.

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove:

If G is a simple, regular graph. Then every vertex has the same amount of vertices on distance (shortest path between 2 vertices) 2. This seems quite clear to me, but I'm struggling to prove it.

I tried to derive a contradiction and induction prove but none of those led me anywhere. I would be grateful if someone can put me on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually false. Look at the 3-regular graph below. The vertices in the center clearly have more vertices with distance 2 than the ones on the outside.

[image: Graphic taken from http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/GIF/10_3_3-1.gif]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was actually a true/false question but I couldn't find a counterexample so I tried proving it.

Comment: Excellent example!